# Icons for iOS Action Extensions Disappearing After Share Button Menu Disappears

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

I've been working on a couple of iOS action extensions for a while, but I have noticed an odd behavior I was wondering if anyone else saw. In short, after you install and turn the extension on from the share button menu and leave the menu, it disappears from the menu.

More specifically, when you first install the extension, you expect you have to press the share button, scroll the bottom bar menu (for the action extensions) all the way to the right, press the "More" button, toggle your extension on and then press done. At that point the icon for the extension will appear and you can use it. However, the next time you want to use the action extension, the icon will not appear and you have to repeat the process, even though when you look in the "More" menu, the toggle switches for your app are already flipped on.

I wish I could add images to further elaborate here, but I can't because of StackOverflow's rules.

I have not been able to find any information on this any where, so I was hoping someone here has noticed this behavior or not. Any help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of iOS? This has been a recurring bug in some versions of iOS 8.x, but it seems to be fixed in 8.3 and I'm pretty sure it was fixed in 8.2.

Comment: For me, this is happening in 8.3, but I one of my colleagues has said he's been seeing it since at least 8.2. Again, for me, this feature was working perfectly well in 8.2.

Comment: Updated my device from 8.2 to 8.3 last night and began experiencing this issue as well. In the "more" menu, I have to toggle my extension off and back on and click "done", and only then I see my extension in the share menu. I have to do this every time I open the share menu and it's quite annoying. Any progress finding a solution?

Comment: I updated to iOS 8.3 and that's when I started seeing this issue for the first time.

Comment: I noticed the same effect on a share extension I am developing. It occurs both on real and simulated devices. Preinstalled extensions (like Twitter) or extensions linked to App Store apps (like 1Password) stay visible once activated. Even toggling a switch for one of those production extensions in the "More" menu also makes my development extension visible again. Did anybody observe an extension disappearing on an app installed through the App Store or TestFlight instead of Xcode?

Comment: The issue seems to be new in 8.3, at least the the 8.2 simulator does not show it

Comment: Did you ever find any information about this?  I'm seeing the same thing.  Building for iOS 8.2 on the simulator "fixes" it but on my phone and the simulator in 8.3 it always disappears after it is used and has to be toggled on/off to come back.

Comment: same issue here. Any updates?

Comment: I'm glad to find this thread but not so glad there's no answer yet. I'm filing a bug report with Apple about it.

Comment: It seems that it's a bug: [App is not showing in the share menu of shared options in shared extension in iOS8][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452686/app-is-not-showing-in-the-share-menu-of-shared-options-in-shared-extension-in-io

Answer (score 2):

This has been a bug in iOS 8.3, and has been acknowledged by Apple.
Fixed in iOS 9.

[Issue on OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4933673157656576)

How to solve:

> The new share extension is NOT visible in the default list, and is CHECKED in the “More…” list. Changing any of the switches and tapping Done will show the new share extension in the default list.