# App is not showing in the share menu of shared options in shared extension in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios8.3, ios8-share-extension

I'm developing share extension for my app.
Every thing is fine, but i'm facing one main problem, my app is not in the share menu while sharing from photos app.

Below is the plist of my shared extension.
[image]

It's not showing in the list, below is the screenshot:

[image]

But when i go to more option, set the switch of my extension off and on, now it is showing in the list, But i need to do it every time, below are the screenshots:

[image] 
[image]

Every time i ran the extension from X-Code, It's not showing the share menu, i need to go to more option, set the switch off and on again, then only it is showing.
Can it show every time in the share menu?
Is there anything i'm missing in the plist or extra configuration required?

I need your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance.
**Update:**
I have checked it in iOS9. It's working fine without any issues.

Comment: Same issue with me. any suggestion for resolve it??

Comment: I'm facing this issue since iOS 14. in safari, app only showing in share option from second attempt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS. There is no workaround in the current version. File a bug report with Apple and hope that they fix it soon.

Comment: But we can see other apps like 'Viber', 'WhatsApp'. Will it show in the share menu once the app is in the App Store?

Comment: The bug only seems to affect development builds installed with Xcode, not apps installed from the app store.

Comment: This has been a bug in iOS 8, and has been acknowledged by Apple. In [iOS 9 beta 4's release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/), this was included: `Debugging an action or sharing extension can cause the extension to be missing in the UIActivityViewController object.`

Comment: I understand this is a bug, but is there any way of testing (not debugging) the app extension without submitting the application to the app store?

Comment: Do the same thing @AshokKumarS describes in the question, turning it off and then back on.

Comment: Is there a bug number for this?

@RizwanSattar I could no longer access this bug listing in the iOS9 release notes.

Comment: @WilliamKu rdar://20905192, http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4933673157656576

Here's a cached changelog from beta 4, which lists the change: http://bgr.com/2015/07/21/ios-9-beta-4-released-change-log/

Answer (score 23):

For anyone having the same problem and not finding a solution, worth trying also to check "Deployment Target" of the extension.

It can be different that the main app and is setup by default when the extension is created.

In my case it was higher than what I had on my device.

Comment: This was the problem for me and it fixed it!  Thanks

Comment: This was my problem too! Thank you SO much!

Comment: This was my case too. Runner deployment target was 9.0 and share extension was 14.0.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this issue on iOS 14 Beta, resolved by restarting the device.

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours of reading in the documentation for the thing I thought I have missed :D

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: Thanks Apple that helped. This also applies for non beta 14.7 devices -.-

Answer (score 5):

#### Step by step flow for creating Share Extension

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then just Run the application

[image]

#### Check Out Plist count to be 1 (1 = allows attachment 1) for images

[image]

Plist

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
    </dict>
```

#### Useful inks

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/

http://www.appcoda.com/tag/app-extension/

#### Sharing data from Extension to Main App information link & How to create Today's extension?

[How to create widgets showing on home screen in iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482917/how-to-create-widgets-showing-on-home-screen-in-ios-10/40484516#40484516)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. I found, that in the Build Settings (of extension target) field Wrapper Extension was empty, while it should be assigned as "appex". Assigning "appex" to Wrapper Extension solved my problem.

[image: Extension Build Settings]

Comment: Jeezus Christ, you saved my life. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered with the same problem and fixed it by changing deployment target version for the extension. In my case ios version of the device that was tested was lower than my target ios version for the extension